# How do I find out which processes are preventing unmounting of a device?

Tags: process, open-files, unmounting

Sometimes, I would like to unmount a **usb device** with `umount /run/media/theDrive`, but I get a `drive is busy` error.

How do I find out which processes or programs are accessing the device?

Comment: more upvotes for same question/answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624154/linux-which-process-is-causing-device-busy-when-doing-umount

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use `lsof | grep /media/whatever` to find out what is using the mount.

Also, consider `umount -l` (lazy umount) to prevent new processes from using the drive while you clean up.

Comment: `fuser -mv /path/to/mountpoint` might be a more readable alternative for finding out processes using a mointpoint.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri  `lsof | grep` works better for me. `fuser -mv` seems to just dump 80+ of unrelated processes. I am using mount binded directories.

Comment: [`umount -l` is dangerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/390056/143394). `mount -o bind`  a mode `000` empty directory on top instead, and clean up via `lsof +f -- /dev/device`.

Answer (score 63):

Most of the time, the best command to use is [lsof](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/) (“**l**i**s**t **o**pen **f**iles”).

```
lsof +f -- /media/usb0
```

where `/media/usb0` is the mount point of the USB drive or other filesystem to unmount. `+f --` tells lsof to treat the subsequent argument as a mount point; it usually, but not always, manages on its own, so that `lsof /media/usb0` also works. This finds open files (even unlinked ones), memory mapped files, current directories, and some more obscure uses. You'll need to run the command as root to get information on other users' processes (and I think there are unices where `lsof` has to be run as root).

There are uses that lsof will not find; these are uncommon on removable media. They include:

- mount points: you can't unmount `/foo` if `/foo/bar` is a mount point.
- mount devices: you can't unmount `/foo` if `/foo/bar` is a mounted block device or loop-mounted regular file, or if it is the source of a Linux bind mount.
- NFS export: lsof won't detect that a tree is exported by a kernel NFS server.

Another command that can serve in a pinch is fuser, which only lists PIDs of processes with open files on the device:

```
fuser -m /media/usb0
```

Answer (score 27):

#### Open files

Processes with open files are the usual culprits. Display them:

```
lsof +f -- <mountpoint or device>
```

There is an advantage to using  `/dev/<device>` rather than `/mountpoint`: a mountpoint will disappear after an `umount -l`, or it may be hidden by an overlaid mount.

`fuser` can also be used, but to my mind `lsof` has a more useful output. However `fuser` is useful when it comes to killing the processes causing your dramas so you can get on with your life.

List files on `<mountpoint>` (see caveat above):

```
fuser -vmM <mountpoint>
```

Interactively kill only processes with files open for writing:

```
fuser -vmMkiw <mountpoint>
```

After remounting read-only (`mount -o remount,ro <mountpoint>`), it is safe(r) to kill all remaining processes:

```
fuser -vmMk <mountpoint>
```

#### Mountpoints

The culprit can be the kernel itself. Another filesystem mounted on the filesystem you are trying to `umount` will cause grief. Check with:

```
mount | grep <mountpoint>/
```

For loopback mounts ([thanks Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/how-do-i-find-out-which-processes-are-preventing-unmounting-of-a-device/386960#comment689190_386960)), also check the output of:

```
losetup -la
```

#### Anonymous inodes (Linux)

[Anonymous inodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4508998/5353461) can be created by:

- Temporary files (`open` with `O_TMPFILE`)
- [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) watches
- [eventfd]
- [eventpoll]
- [timerfd]

These are the most elusive type of pokemon, and appear in `lsof`'s `TYPE` column as `a_inode` (which is undocumented in the  [`lsof` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)).

They won't appear in `lsof +f -- /dev/<device>`, so you'll need to:

```
lsof | grep a_inode
```

For killing processes holding anonymous inodes, see: [List current inotify watches (pathname, PID)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386877/143394).

#### `inotify` watches (Linux)

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951874/system-call-interface-to-proc-information#comment78876871_45951874) explains why `inotify` *shouldn't* prevent an unmount, but [this note](https://sort.symantec.com/public/documents/sfha/5.1sp1/linux/productguides/html/sf_notes/ch01s09s04s12.htm) describes the situations in which it *will*:

> an unmount can hang in the `vx_softcnt_flush()` call. The hang occurs because inotify watches increment the `i_count` variable and cause the `v_os_hold value` to remain elevated until the inotify watcher releases the hold.

Comment: There’s another one, loopback mounts: if you mount a file system, then mount a file on that file system using a loopback mount, you won’t be able to unmount the first file system, but nothing will show up in `lsof`.

Comment: Cheers. Added to the `Mountpoints` section.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `lsof` like Peter said, or if you're sure you just want to kill all those things and unmount it, you can probably do something like:

```
fuser -Mk /mnt/path
umount /mnt/path
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, look into using `-M` for safety.

Comment: @TomHale You might want to make clear which command `-M` should be applied to.

Comment: `fuser`:  `-M, --ismountpoint                                                                                                                                                                                          
              Request will be fulfilled only if NAME specifies a mountpoint.  This is an invaluable seatbelt which prevents you from killing the machine if NAME happens to not be a filesystem.`

Answer (score 7):

If you use GNOME, unmounting via Nautilus will display a message stating which process is still using the drive, and the file it's using.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For (at least) OpenBSD:

```
$ fstat /mnt/mountpoint
```

For example (using `doas` to execute `fstat` as root as we otherwise would only see our own processes):

```
$ doas fstat /usr/ports
USER     CMD          PID   FD MOUNT        INUM MODE         R/W    SZ|DV NAME
_pbuild  make       15172   wd /usr/ports  3923598  drwxrwxr-x     r     1536 /usr/ports/
_pbuild  make       40034   wd /usr/ports  3923598  drwxrwxr-x     r     1536 /usr/ports/
```

In this case, I would not be able to unmount `/usr/ports` until user `_pbuild` had finished running those two `make` processes.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add one other scenario to look out for.

**Is your partition being exported as an NFS mount?**

If so, you need to remove it from `/etc/exports` and run `sudo exportf -ra`

Then you should be able to umount the partition.  Might seem obvious, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common pitfall: You su to a different user (either root or any other user), change to the directory of a mounted device, and then log out as that user. When you forget that you left in that directory, you can try and find until you are blind. `lsof` does show the shell which current directory is using that device. You might want to su as that user again to change your directory.

Comment: This answer is either incomplete or incorrect. I'm not sure which because it is also unclear.