# How to find out which process keeps an LVM partition from unmounting *during shutdown*?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, unmounting

I see that LVM1 (/dev/mapper/lvm1--vg-lvm1--lv) fails to umount during the shutdown, when I cannot run one of [the](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11713/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-preventing-a-umount) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624154/linux-which-process-is-causing-device-busy-when-doing-umount) [options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/how-do-i-find-out-which-processes-are-preventing-unmounting-of-a-device) to find out which process or user is holding up the mountpoint.

It also seems that there is no log kept which I could look into.

**How do I log or at least display which process is locking the disk during a shutdown?**

PS: Ubuntu 18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enable debugging with below options.

```
-d|--debug : Set  debug  level.  Repeat  from  1  to 6 times to increase the detail of messages sent to the log file and/or syslog (if configured).  Overrides config file setting.
-v|--verbose : Set verbose level. Repeat from 1 to 3 times to increase the detail  of  messages  sent  to  stdout  and stderr.  Overrides config file setting.
```